# How to upload document versions with keywords/metadata/etc changes included?

Tags: 2010, powershell, metadata, move

The situation is as follows: there is a document on two sites - on site A in versions 1-20 and on site B there are versions 20 - 27. Users are working only on the document located on site B - changing content, title, adding/removing keywords and metadata etc.

I would like to merge these copies so that I have only one copy with versions 1-27 as a result. I wrote some PowerShell scripts that allow me to download all the versions from site B as separate files and add them to the document on site A but I am missing the whole keywords and metadata history. I mean - for example - someone added a keyword in version 25 but in the result file, that I get when using my scripts, there is no indication of that action below version 25 in "Show history".

Is it possible to "move" all the actions performed during version change along with the proper files so that they are visible in "Show history" in right place?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the documents whose versions I try to merge are Office 2010 documents, all the necessary metadata is stored inside the documents (vide [How is metadata stored?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34164/how-is-metadata-stored)).

So when I upload each version, every change made to that version is automatically applied to the version history.